# How to remove empty dictionaries from this list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list:

```
lst = [('2019R', {'entities': []}, {'entities': []}, {'entities': []}, {'entities': []}), 
       ('United States', {'entities': []}, {'entities': [(0, 28, 'ORG')]}, {'entities': []}, {'entities': []}), 
       ('Rick Miller', {'entities': [(0, 11, 'PERSON')]}, {'entities': [(22, 37, 'ORG')]}, 
        {'entities': []}, {'entities': []})]
```

*I tried to solve it using list comprehension as mentioned below, but did not get success:*

```
new_data = [x for x in lst if x[1]['entities']]
```

output I received:

```
[('Rick Miller', {'entities': [(0, 11, 'PERSON')]}, {'entities': [(22, 37, 'ORG')]}, {'entities': []}, {'entities': []})]
```

*Another way I tried it by:*

```
x = [i for i in lst if len(i) > 1]
```

Output I received:

```
[('2019R', {'entities': []}, {'entities': []}, {'entities': []}, {'entities': []}), ('United States District Court', {'entities': []}, {'entities': [(0, 28, 'ORG')]}, {'entities': []}, {'entities': []}), ('Rick Miller works for Bank of Tokyo', {'entities': [(0, 11, 'PERSON')]}, {'entities': [(22, 37, 'ORG')]}, {'entities': []}, {'entities': []})]
```

**I need only bellow to be stored in another list. The rest should be discarded as mentioned below.
Expected final Output:**

```
    new_data = [('United States', {'entities': [(0, 28, 'ORG')]}, 
                ('Rick Miller', {'entities': [(0, 11, 'PERSON')]}, {'entities': [(22, 37, 'ORG')]})]
```

Comment: `result = [l for l in lst if any(<completeme> for l_ in l[1:])]` good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def empty(item):

    if isinstance(item, dict):
        return not bool(item["entities"])

    return False

result = [tuple(item for item in tuples if not empty(item)) for tuples in lst]

# further removing tuples of length 1
result = [item for item in result if not len(item) == 1]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
    ("United States", {"entities": [(0, 28, "ORG")]}),
    ("Rick Miller", {"entities": [(0, 11, "PERSON")]}, {"entities": [(22, 37, "ORG")]}),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can do it in one line but will defeat readability:

```
x = [(a, *filter(lambda i: len(i["entities"]), b)) for a, *b in lst]
print([i for i in x if len(i) > 1])
```

Output:

```
[('United States', {'entities': [(0, 28, 'ORG')]}), ('Rick Miller', {'entities': [(0, 11, 'PERSON')]}, {'entities': [(22, 37, 'ORG')]})]
```

The `*b` means collecting all the remaining items to b and the `*` before the filter means unpacking them into the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this, but you can do a fairly straight-forward list comprehension using assignment expressions:

```
>>> lst = [('2019R', {'entities': []}, {'entities': []}, {'entities': []}, {'entities': []}),
...        ('United States', {'entities': []}, {'entities': [(0, 28, 'ORG')]}, {'entities': []}, {'entities': []}),
...        ('Rick Miller', {'entities': [(0, 11, 'PERSON')]}, {'entities': [(22, 37, 'ORG')]},
...         {'entities': []}, {'entities': []})]
```

Then just:

```
>>> new_data = [
...     (name, *clean) for name, *data in lst
...     if any(clean:=[d for d in data if d['entities']])
... ]
```

So:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(new_data)
[('United States', {'entities': [(0, 28, 'ORG')]}),
 ('Rick Miller',
  {'entities': [(0, 11, 'PERSON')]},
  {'entities': [(22, 37, 'ORG')]})]
```